# Unable to call macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am using Excel 2010 and I have been unable to call a macro. I have three worksheets, one where my chart (Sheet 1) is displayed and therein lies a table for a dynamic chart, a worksheet for raw data input (Sheet 2) and lastly a worksheet whereby data is formatted from the raw data through formulas (Sheet 3).

The macro to insert the new row in the table is as follows:

```
Sub SBTrend()
'
' SBTrend Macro
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
    Range("BA10").Select
End Sub
```

The code that I have to call the macro in Sheet 3 is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Static OldVal As Variant
If Range("A9").Value <> OldVal Then
    OldVal = Range("A9").Value
    Call SBTrend
End If
End Sub
```

However, I am always faced with the error "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set." And when I debug, this line gets highlighted:

```
Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
```

I would really appreciate any and all the help I can get. Thank you everyone.

Comment: You need to remove the `Selection` - the calculate event can fire when a worksheet isn't active.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the `ListObjects` collection.

If there is only one table on the worksheet you can just reference the table by it's index

```
With Sheets("Sheet 1")
    .Select
    .ListObjects(1).ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
End With
Range("BA10").Select
```

If there are multiple you should reference the table by it's name

```
With Sheets("Sheet 1")
    .Select
    .ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
End With
Range("BA10").Select
```

Comment: Thanks a million Thomas! You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but now I have another issue. The raw data sheet (Sheet 2), has a user form embedded. Before the macro, the data is transferred to Sheet 2, however, with the macro working now, the data is transferred to Sheet 1. May I have your opinion on this issue? Thanks again!

Comment: There is really a need to use select or activate.  You should post your code and ask how to make it work without selecting Sheet1.